# How to ensure ScriptableObjects are unique when copied in the Unity 3D editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity 3D, I have a `MonoBehaviour` which contains a list of class derivates which all are based on a common `ScriptableObject`.
The list is filled and handled in a custom editor. This works flawlessly, but with one exception: Whenever I copy/paste my `MonoBehaviour`, or duplicate a game object holding it in the Unity editor, my list contains only instances and not unique clones.

Here's some example code (note that this is only stripped down test code, my actual classes are much more complex, which requires a separate data class):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class MyAbstractBaseClass : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract void foo();
}

public class MyTestScriptableObject : MyAbstractBaseClass
{
    public string stringMember;
    public override void foo()
    {
    }
}

public class MyTestMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<MyAbstractBaseClass> testList;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(MyTestMonoBehaviour))]
public class MyTestMonoBehaviourEditor : Editor
{
    const int NUM_LISTENTRIES = 5;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        SerializedProperty testListProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("testList");

        for (int i = 0; i < testListProp.arraySize; i++)
        {
            SerializedObject myTestScriptableObjectSO = new SerializedObject(testListProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).objectReferenceValue);
            SerializedProperty stringMemberProp = myTestScriptableObjectSO.FindProperty("stringMember");
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(stringMemberProp);
            myTestScriptableObjectSO.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        if( GUILayout.Button("Generate List"))
        {
            testListProp.arraySize = NUM_LISTENTRIES;
            for( int i=0; i<NUM_LISTENTRIES; i++)
                testListProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).objectReferenceValue = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<MyTestScriptableObject>();
        }
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Like I said, this code works flawlessly with the exception of the reference/clone issue. This means, when I change string 1 on GameObject A, string 1 on the copied GameObject B is also changed.
I could of course easily clone the `ScriptableObject` references with `ScriptableObject.Instantiate()` - my problem is, that I don't know WHEN to clone.

My questions are:

- Is there any callback/virtual method or similar which tells me, when my `MonoBehaviour` is duplicated in the editor (via C&P or duplicated GameObjects?)
- Alternatively, is there any kind of reference counting in C# or Unity-wise, which can tell me, how often an object is referenced? Since it's only editor code, a method using reflection would be also ok.
- Is `ScriptableObject` the best choice for the base of a data class which has to be unique at all, or are there alternatives?

frankhermes already suggested in the comments to use simple serialized data classes. This works fine for a single class, but unfortunately not for class hierarchies with a base class, since afaik they are not supported in the Unity serialization.

Comment: It seems like Scriptable Objects are not the right choice for your use case, why don't you just use Strings in your MonoBehaviour? ScriptableObjects are meant to be re-used and referenced?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The code I posted is of course only test code - the actual classes are much more complicated than one single string member: a base class and multiple derivates with differing members. This would make it very awkward to handle all of this in the MonoBehaviour itself, so I think I need a separate data class. I also already asked myself, if there could be an alternative to using ScriptableObject as the base of my data class. I will extend my question according to this.

Comment: You could have a separate data class that is not saved into a Scriptable Object, but serialized into your Monobehaviour instance. Then it would be cloned when you copy or duplicate the GameObject instead of referring to the separate Scriptable Object.

Comment: Hm... have to think about that... thank you

Comment: Tried it out now, doesn't work for a class hierarchy. Adjusted my question according to this.

Comment: Yes I was already wondering how to get around that. How about using `OnValidate` to be notified of copied instances? Or adding a button to your custom editor that you click after having copied some instance and creating new ScriptableObject instances for your copy?

Comment: The button already works for now as a workaround, but lets say... its not very good style and very error prone ;)
I've found a possible solution here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/483434/how-to-call-a-method-when-a-gameobject-has-been-du.html
I will try to evaluate it with the instance id of the game object the monobehaviour resides on and post an answer tomorrow if I'm successful.

Comment: Solution works. Thanks for your effort, frankhermes :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

***--- Caution ---***

*This answer only works partially. The unique instance id CHANGES between sessions, which makes it useless for clone detection and serializing :(
https://answers.unity.com/questions/863084/does-getinstanceid-ever-change-on-an-object.html*

.

Found the solution at [in the Unity forum](https://answers.unity.com/questions/483434/how-to-call-a-method-when-a-gameobject-has-been-du.html):
Storing and checking the instance id of the `GameObject` the `MonoBehaviour` is attached to works very good (see `MakeListElementsUnique()`).

The only situation where this will fail is if you copy a `MonoBehaviour` and paste it to the same `GameObject`. But this isn't a real problem for my use case and for many others I suppose.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class MyAbstractBaseClass : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract void foo();
}

public class MyTestScriptableObject : MyAbstractBaseClass
{
    public string stringMember;
    public override void foo()
    {
    }
}

public class MyTestMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int instanceID = 0;
    public List<MyAbstractBaseClass> testList;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(MyTestMonoBehaviour))]
public class MyTestMonoBehaviourEditor : Editor
{
    const int NUM_LISTENTRIES = 5;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        MyTestMonoBehaviour myScriptableObject = (MyTestMonoBehaviour)target;

        SerializedProperty testListProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("testList");

        MakeListElementsUnique(myScriptableObject, testListProp);

        for (int i = 0; i < testListProp.arraySize; i++)
        {

            SerializedObject myTestScriptableObjectSO = new SerializedObject(testListProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).objectReferenceValue);
            SerializedProperty stringMemberProp = myTestScriptableObjectSO.FindProperty("stringMember");
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(stringMemberProp);
            myTestScriptableObjectSO.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate List"))
        {
            testListProp.arraySize = NUM_LISTENTRIES;
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LISTENTRIES; i++)
                testListProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i).objectReferenceValue = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<MyTestScriptableObject>();
        }
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void MakeListElementsUnique( MyTestMonoBehaviour scriptableObject, SerializedProperty testListProp )
    {
        SerializedProperty instanceIdProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("instanceID");
        // stored instance id == 0: freshly created, just set the instance id of the game object
        if (instanceIdProp.intValue == 0)
        {
            instanceIdProp.intValue = scriptableObject.gameObject.GetInstanceID();
        }
        // stored instance id != current instance id: copied!
        else if (instanceIdProp.intValue != scriptableObject.gameObject.GetInstanceID())
        {
            // don't forget to change the instance id to the new game object
            instanceIdProp.intValue = scriptableObject.gameObject.GetInstanceID();
            // make clones of all list elements
            for (int i = 0; i < testListProp.arraySize; i++)
            {
                SerializedProperty sp = testListProp.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
                sp.objectReferenceValue = Object.Instantiate(sp.objectReferenceValue);
            }
        }
    }

}
```